# MSM Server Path Problems after upgrade to EE3

Tags: multi-site-manager

I am in the process of upgrading an MSM configuration from EE 2.11.x to 3.5.7 and have run into the following error on the MSM site:

> Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please
>   open the following file and correct this: index.php

Before the upgrade the path I was using to reference the system folder was this:

```
/home/sitename/public_html/system/
```

That has not changed but now I get the error message.

Any guidance on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out in this case that it was server settings that were preventing the communication between sites. It required:

- Mod_ruid was disabled
- suPHP enabled
- FileProtect in Home »Server Configuration »Tweak Settings turned off

Great support from KnownHost.